# Eloquent - SQLite query nested value in json column

Tags: json, laravel, sqlite, eloquent

I'm having an issue with my testing environment when using json columns.

In my tests I use an SQLite database and I have realised that my queries fails when accesing json columns... I dont know how to face it. I'm running latest version of Homestead.

My problem is:

I have an User model with a **settings** json column where I store a boolean value named **mailing**, so, if I want to query all Users with mailing true I can write:

```php
User::where('settings->mailing', true)->count();
```

And then, this throws me an error:

```sql
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such column: true (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from "users" where json_extract("settings", '$."mailing"') = true)
```

In my local environment using MySQL its working fine, so, is there a problem with SQLite and json column queries?

**Another tip:** When using `whereNull()` or `whereNotNull()` its working fine too in both environments.

Thanks!

Comment: SQLite added TRUE and FALSE support in 3.23.1: https://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_23_1.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to used it as a string:

```
User::where('settings->mailing', 'true')->count();
```

yes there is some restriction over sqlLite [have a look](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#json-where-clauses)

Comment: As per laravel 5.7 this support Currently, this includes MySQL 5.7, PostgreSQL, SQL Server 2016, and SQLite 3.9.0 (with the JSON1 extension).

Comment: Thanks for replying. Using the string solves the error but its still not querying if saved as a boolean `$user->forceFill(['settings->mailing' => true])->save()`. It returns me 0 Users...

Comment: which version of laravel are you using??

Comment: I'm using latest versions, exactly 7.5.2

Comment: have you gone through the link i have provided in my answer for just making sure your version support.

Comment: I guess there is some limitation for the boolean value query as per laravel.